# Redirecting using href attributes in asp.net mvc application not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

I use navigation like this:

```
<a href="/MyMessages/?messageId=1"> First message </>
```

But before the user is navigated I handle the event in JavaScript:

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Do stuff
    // Navigate:
    location.pathname = $(this).attr('href'); // href is /MyMessages/?messageId=1
});
```

But it gets encoded in browser, and the address is:

```
localhost:52500/MyMessages/%3FmessageId=1
```

and the mvc routing fails:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (?).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path
>   value was detected from the client (?).]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9807692
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53

But when I just navigate by deeplinking like

```
localhost:52500/MyMessages/?messageId=1
```

everything works.

How to avoid my browser encoding my url and preventing the error I get?

Answer (score 0):

if the last thing you do in your event handler is go to the exact href, then remove:-

```
location.pathname = $(this).attr('href');
```

and make sure you DONT `preventDefault` or `return false;`.

The browser will redirect using the `href` off the `anchor` after the click event as normal.

> User can also choose to stay on the page (popup has yes/no buttons,
>   after preventing default if its dirty), and then if he chooses to
>   navigate again, the same would happen

try something like:-

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    if(dirty){
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#yes').attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
       $('#popup').show();
    }
});
```

and create the `#yes` as an anchor.

Comment: That works. However, my implementation required that I prevent default so the browser doesn't generate popups. Is there a way around it like this?

Comment: generate popups? can you explain that a little more?

Comment: I mark the form as dirty and generate a custom popup informing the user there are unsaved changed when navigating. And for that to work (not to show the generic browser popup), but instead show my own custom popup I have to preventDefault.

Comment: why dont you preventDefault `if` its dirty. otherwise dont and let it run and allow the anchor to redirect.

Comment: User can also choose to stay on the page (popup has yes/no buttons, after preventing default if its dirty), and then if he chooses to navigate again, the same would happen

Comment: Then the button/link they click when choosing to navigate away, set that as an `a` and give it the correct `href`. without seeing more code its difficult to see the issue.